# rendering pdf using Quarto

Tags: parameters, yaml, rstudio, quarto, renderdoc

I'm having an issue with inserting parameter values into a Quarto document. Despite defining a parameter in the YAML header, the document renders the literal text **r params$name** instead of substituting it with the parameter's value, "John Doe".

I'm not sure why the parameter substitution is not occurring as expected. Could I be missing a step, or is there a specific way to enable parameter evaluation in Quarto documents?

Any assistance or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Here a version of what I found following [this](https://meghan.rbind.io/blog/2022-09-25-tips-for-custom-parameterized-pdfs-in-quarto/#rendering-parameterized-reports) post and [this](https://www.jhelvy.com/posts/2023-02-28-parameterized-pdfs-with-quarto/) one.

```
---
format:
  pdf:
    toc: false
    number-sections: false
    documentclass: article
    papersize: letter
    fontsize: 12pt
    geometry:
      - margin=1in
      - heightrounded
params:
  name: "John Doe"
---


# Feedback for Homework 1

**Student**: `r params$name`
```

I'm using the latest version of Rstudio and Quarto Client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer [here](https://github.com/quarto-dev/quarto-cli/discussions/4855). Just adding

> engine: knitr

to the YAML.